# Split square brackets into commas, remove first and last comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have written the following console log to convert a list of [] to commas:

```
[Item 1][Item 2][Item 3][Item 4]
...

.split(/[[\]]{1,2}/);
```

but I am getting the following printed out:

```
,Item 1,Item 2,Item 3,Item 4,
```

when I am looking for:

```
Item 1,Item 2,Item 3,Item 4
```

I have tried a variety of different approaches but none provide me with the above last result.

Comment: `.split` returns an array. Call `.join(',')` on it, and you'll have your result.

Comment: `"[Item 1][Item 2][Item 3][Item 4]".match(/Item \d/g).join(",")` - Also the input example is syntactically invalid and the example outputs show complete ignorance to the type of the output, which makes this a happy guessing - so i downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `match` instead of `split` and take directly the result array.

```js
var string = '[Item 1][Item 2][Item 3][Item 4]',
    parts = string.match(/[^\[\]]+/g);

console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without going with regex, you could just slice it before splitting.

```js
var str = "[Item 1][Item 2][Item 3][Item 4]";
var result = str.slice(1,-1).split`][`;
console.log(result);
```

The regex option would be:

```js
var str = "[Item 1][Item 2][Item 3][Item 4]";
var result = str.match(/[\w ]+/g);
console.log(result);
```